# Way to access response data outside the scope of axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

this is my first time to develop a react application.

I will be using the get response of axios to populate a table. The outside var is declared and used outside the scope of the axios.

Is there a way to use the get response of axios outside/ in global scope?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

let rows = [];

  axios
    .get(`url here`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
     }
    });


  //access res outside scope - is this possible?
  rows.push({res.data});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some form of state to keep track of the rows.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  // Initialize a rows state variable that will be set to [] on the initial load.
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the data when the component is mounted
    axios
      .get(`url here`)
      .then(res => {
        // Store the response (the rows) in the state variable.
        setRows(res)
      })
  }, [])

  /*
   * On the initial mount nothing will be rendered, when the rows variable
   * is updated a re-render will be triggered and your rows can be rendered.
   */
  return (
    <div>
     { rows.map(row => <tr>A row!</tr>) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

I suggest reading https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score -2):

```js
const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

  let responseData = {};

  let rows = [];

  axios
    .get(`url here`)
    .then(res => responseData = res.data);


  //access res outside scope - is possible by creating a global variable and assign value to it in the scope.

  rows.push({responseData });
}
```